# How to tell thread-pool to run a delegate on a `STA` thread?

Tags: c#, threadpool, sta

I need a thread-pool for working with `COM` objects inside an `ASP.NET` project.

```
QueueUserWorkItemSTA(WaitCallback)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the CodeProject Article of [Smart Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx):

> Also note that the .NET ThreadPool
>   doesn't support calls to COM with
>   single threaded apartment (STA), since
>   the ThreadPool threads are MTA by
>   design.

So I assume if you give the Smart Thread Pool a try, it could fit your requirements.

Personally, I use this class successfully since severals years.

Comment: Thanks, I was planning writing one myself !

Comment: So, how do we now flag the threads from this SmartPoolThread as STA?? Are these threads STA by default?